# Consume Xml "AS IS" using BizTalk Sql Adapter

Tags: biztalk

I have a stored procedure which returns a fully formed schema instance as an xml datatype:

```
<ns0:PolicyCreated xmlns:ns0="http://blah/v1.0">
  <ns0:Source>
    <ns0:Organisation>Company1</ns0:Organisation>
    <ns0:System>System1</ns0:System>
  </ns0:Source>
</ns0:PolicyCreated>
```

The problem is when I try to consume this with the Sql Adapter it wraps the xml in a root node and namespace:

```
<ns0:PolicyCreated xmlns:ns0="http://blah/v1.0">
  <ns0:PolicyCreated xmlns:ns0="http://blah/v1.0">
    <ns0:Source>
      <ns0:Organisation>Company1</ns0:Organisation>
      <ns0:System>System1</ns0:System>
    </ns0:Source>
  </ns0:PolicyCreated>
</ns0:PolicyCreated>
```

So I get a double root node and namespace.

Any ideas how can I get around this?

Thanks in adavnce

Tom

Comment: Can you share the request and response schemas?  Is this the BizTalk 2006 SQL Adapter or the WCF SQL Adapter?

Comment: Hi Chris there are no request/response schemas. I am not consuming an adapter metadata. This is a one way receive. I just want to receive xml as is from SQL adapter, similar to how you would with the MSMQ or FILE adapters. It seems there is a way to do this with WCF SQL adapter because you can specify the body xpath in the send port response. However, with SQL

Comment: Did you try to make a envelope schema for the XML coming back out of thew SQL Adapter?. Use the 'anyType/maxOccurs=unbounded' for the sub document(s). Although you might not really be doing enveloppe processing, the double root element is gone since it's considered a enveloppe element, not a document element. You should end up with your seperate rows coming into the MessageBox 'as-is' (FOR XML AUTO)

Comment: Thanks for that Marvin. I didn't get a chance to try this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: It seems there is a way to do this with WCF SQL adapter because you can specify the body xpath on the response message in the send port WCF configutation.

However, this is just wasteful because all you are doing is telling the adapter to "unwrap" the xml and then apply another, identical, wrapper.

With SQL adapter there is no such option. So there is no way to do what I want to do, but it's not the end of the world. I will just have to specify a different wrapper in the sql adapter configuration and have another schema to maintain.